# Count occurrences of a specific sequence in a list of many numbers

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, python-3.x, homework

The script will work through each number from 0 - 10.

```
aList=[3,5,... over 10k numbers ...,2,2,6]
```

Let’s say, for example: `findSquence01=[3,5]` or `findSquence02=[3,5,3]`

```
count = 0
for i in range(len(data)-len(pattern)+1):
    tmp = [data[i], data [i+1]]

    try:
        for j in range(len(data)-i):
            print(i, i+j)
            if tmp[-1] != data[i+j+1]:
                tmp.append(data[i+j+1])

            if len(tmp) == len(pattern):
                print(tmp)
                break
    except:
        pass

    if tmp == pattern:
        count +=1
```

> i- represents times of [3,5]
>
> j- represents times of [3,5,3]

```
print("There is",i,"times",findSquence01)
print("There is",j,"times",findSquence02)
```

The output should look like:

> There is 73 times [3,5]
>
> There is 12 times [3,5,3]

How can I walk through the list and count those given sequences?

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep your solution as general as possible. If I'm reading your code snippet right, you're trying to solve the problem for two patterns simultaneously. Instead, write a simple function that takes a list and a pattern, and just loops through the list counting occurrences of the pattern. This is a nice use case for list slices: given a list `a`, `a[i:j]` is a list consisting of elements `i` through `j-1` of `a`.

```
def count_sequence(lst, seq):
     count = 0
     len_seq = len(seq)
     upper_bound = len(lst)-len_seq+1
     for i in range(upper_bound):
         if lst[i:i+len_seq] == seq:
             count += 1
     return count
```

Try to avoid exceptions if possible*. A rule of thumb is that exceptions are for *exceptional* situations. In your case, you're designing your code around the fact that you're going to get `IndexError`s, whereas the function I wrote keeps the array bounds in mind and thus won't raise `IndexError`s. Additionally, never write `except: pass`. The point of the `except` block is to catch errors and do something with them, so don't pass over them.

---

* Python itself doens't always follow this advice; for example, loops in Python are ended by raising the `StopIteration` exception. Nevertheless, for user-level code it's usually a good idea to only use exceptions if absolutely necessary.

Comment: "Never write `except: pass` ...": Whilst this holds in this situation, there's certainly times when `except: pass` is valid. As for handling out-of-bounds access, either style is valid (EAFTP = Easier to Ask for Forgiveness Than Permission states that the preferred method is by catching exceptions).

Comment: @Daniel: Avoiding `except: pass` is usually a good idea, even in EAFTP style. Instead you want to be specific about the kind of exception you expect (so e.g. `except KeyError: pass`).

Comment: @Graipher "Avoiding ... style.": Absolutely, my second remark was with regards to the overall approach, i.e. manually keep track of the length of the containers and make sure out-of-bounds access is disallowed, or trust Python to raise an `IndexError` and handle that case (EAFTP encourages the latter).